# I get this error when trying to connect to a graphcool relay API from a react app: Module build failed: Error: No valid GraphQL endpoint

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, graphcool

I am following a tutorial from Lynda.com 'Deploying a fullstack react application'. I am using the 'create-react-app project to scaffold my project. For some unknown reason, my app can't access the api, which I can access directly without any issues on the browser. Here's my package.json file, I get the error whenever I run 'yarn start'.

```
  {
  "name": "tictacturing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-relay": "^1.4.1",
    "relay-runtime": "^1.4.1",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjazdk3jg0yj70197193cltrf && node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "set GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjazdk3jg0yj70197193cltrf && node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "mjs",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "react-relay"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-relay": "^0.10.0",
    "eslint": "^4.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update these two lines:

```
"start": "set GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjazdk3jg0yj70197193cltrf && node scripts/start.js",
"build": "set GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjazdk3jg0yj70197193cltrf && node scripts/build.js",
```

with these two lines:

```
"start": "set GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjazdk3jg0yj70197193cltrf&&node scripts/start.js",
"build": "set GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjazdk3jg0yj70197193cltrf&&node scripts/build.js",
```

There should be no spaces between and around `&&`. Do mark it as correct answer if this solves your question

Comment: Wow! Awesome answer.. I never would have thought to remove the spaces on && in the scripts. Thanks Karan!

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the service in the first place?

It looks like you might have created it locally only.

`https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjazdk3jg0yj70197193cltrf` indeed is no valid GraphQL endpoint, it does not exist.

**Edit:**

Update these two lines

```
"start": "set GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjazdk3jg0yj70197193cltrf && node scripts/start.js",
"build": "set GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjazdk3jg0yj70197193cltrf && node scripts/build.js",
```

to

```
"start": "set GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjb223en111od0191dzu1vba4 && node scripts/start.js",
"build": "set GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjb223en111od0191dzu1vba4 && node scripts/build.js",
```

When you deleted the project `cjazdk3jg0yj70197193cltrf`, the endpoint got removed as well.

Comment: I created the project on console.graph.cool. Here's the new endpoint 'https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cjb223en111od0191dzu1vba4'. I took down the old one while troubleshooting the problem. The service was created on graph.cool

Comment: Hi marktani, the endpoints have been updated. But the problem persists. The problem is why I am getting this error when the endpoint clearly exists and is accessible.

Comment: Please share more about your project setup, it looks like a misconfiguration in one of your files :)